# Pycharm won't upgrade packages

Tags: pycharm, pypi, requirements.txt

I'm having an odd error while I'm trying to upgrade requirements.txt packages in Pycharm 2016.3.1.

Everything was ok until 10 minutes ago...

If I click on upgrade any library I get the next error.

[image: Error I'm having]

*Error occurred. Please, check your internet connection.*

I don't know what to do, I re-create the virtualenv with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. Please check your requirements.txt. Maybe it is wrong in some way (e.g. "=" instead "==", that was my mistake).

Comment: OMG, I had this exact mistake! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I was at my work's computer system, because it was behind a proxy. If it's a similar situation, you can fix it by setting the manual proxy configurations of PyCharm as follows:

1. Open PyCharm, go to File then Settings.
2. Click at HTTP Proxy under the System Settings.
3. Click and enable the "Manual proxy configuration" box and "HTTP".
4. Fill in Hostname of the proxy server you want to connect to and enter   the port number which is being used by the proxy server. Add authentication details if it is needed.
5. Click Apply then OK to close the dialog box

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly this doesn't fix my problem. I'm on the same home PC, and other projects work ok.

Comment: The only other problem I may think is that the repository for the packaging has been deleted or changed. You can check that on Settings>Project Interpreter>click "+"> Manage Repositories>click "+" and check it the `https://pypi.python.org/simple/` repo is there